# I switch window's rootViewContrller (vcA) to vcB, but dealloc method of vcA do not fire. The vcA has some operation, see below

Tags: ios, rootviewcontroller

the key window's rootViewController is a login ViewController。In the login viewController, i will modal or push other viewControllers.
 When login successfully, it would switch the rootViewController to viewController C. I find the login viewController's dealloc method is not fired.

I found same question similarity my question, but not resolve my question.

The test demo code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
ViewControllerA *vc =  [[ViewControllerA alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = vc;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

In the viewControllerA(vcA), i modal viewControllerB(vcB)

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

ViewControllerB *vcB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:vcB animated:YES completion: nil];

}
```

In the vcB, i switch the key window's rootViewController to vcC

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
//        [keyWindow.rootViewController removeFromParentViewController]; 
//        keyWindow.rootViewController = nil; 
keyWindow.rootViewController = [ViewControllerC new];
```

you will find, the dealloc method of vcA will not fire.

If i dismiss the vcB when switch the rootViewController, it would be good

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion: nil];

UIWindow *keyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
//        [keyWindow.rootViewController removeFromParentViewController]; // 无效
//        keyWindow.rootViewController = nil; // 无效
keyWindow.rootViewController = [ViewControllerC new];
```

so, what should i do to dealloc vcA?

Here is my test demo [enter link description here](https://github.com/againxu/test-demo.git)

Comment: Could you show us your whole implementation of vcA ?

Comment: @Randy in the test demo , the vcA just modal vcB, like:  
`[self presentViewController:vcB animated:YES completion: nil];`

Comment: @Randy you can see my test demo in my github [link](https://github.com/againxu/test-demo.git)

Comment: Have you taken a look in Instruments, to see if there is a hanging reference?

Comment: @Stephen I used leaks tool to view, but found no leaks

Comment: @Stephen maybe you would like to run my demo, here is the link [link](https://github.com/againxu/test-demo.git)

Comment: I believe the best practice here would be to dismiss the viewcontrollers until you hit the root, then switch the rootviewcontroller out. I did some testing with your project and found that works (like in your example above, and the commented out line in your test).

I believe the reason is that vcA has a strong reference to vcB and vcB has one to vcA, as part of managing the view hierarchy.

Comment: @Stephen yes, it would be good to dismiss the viewcontrollers. But 
controller a modal controller b, b modal c, in turn go on a number of times, it would be trouble to dismiss controllers. How could i switch the rootviewcontroller friendly? I want to get the other method to do it. It's very appreciable